# Pin it button error : Invalid source URL

Tags: magento-1.9, product-view, social-buttons

I am using below methods to generate pinit button

```
protected function getPinterestHref()
{
    $params = array();

    $url = 'url=' . $this->getProductUrlShared();
    $params[] = $url;

    $media = 'media=' . $this->getProductMediaShared();
    $params[] = $media;

    $description = 'description=' . $this->getProductDescriptionShared();
    $params[] = $description;

    $src = 'http://www.pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url='. implode('&', $params);

    return $src;
}

protected function getProductUrlShared()
{
    return urlencode(Mage::registry('product')->getProductUrl());
}

protected function getProductMediaShared()
{
    return urlencode(Mage::registry('product')->getImageUrl());
}

protected function getProductDescriptionShared()
{
    return Mage::registry('product')->getName();
}
```

i am getting the below error

> Parameter 'source_url' (value http://xyz.abc.com/meemee/asd.html) is
>   not a valid URL format.

what am i doing wrong ?

Comment: Check is there any space in URL? Check page source

Comment: already trimmed

Comment: Try secure URL in pin

Comment: is it required to have SSL to pin to pinintrest  ?

Comment: Not sure but see here [Pinterest button - Parameter 'source_url' -is not a valid URL format](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25932271/5668224).